# How to update html header after login in an angular/node.js application?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get a header to update after login. I have used both `$on` and `$watch` in this effort to no avail. When I refresh it works correctly. Code is as follows below.

header.html (missing excess nav bar code for simplicity)

```
<li><a ng-href="#/login" ng-hide="showMenu">Login</a></li>
<li><a ng-href="#/signup" ng-hide="showMenu">Signup</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:" ng-click="logout()" ng-show="showMenu">Logout</a></li>
```

app.js

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    url: '',
    views: {
      'header': {
            templateUrl: 'views/partials/_header.html',
            controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

header.js (The broadcast fires correctly as demonstrated by the console.logs)

```
angular.module('urbinsight')
.controller('HeaderCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $location, UserAuthFactory, AuthFactory) {

$scope.logout = function () {
  UserAuthFactory.logout();
  $rootScope.$broadcast('loginStateChange');
  $location.path('/');
};

$scope.showMenu = AuthFactory.loggedStatus();

$rootScope.$on('loginStateChange', function(){
  console.log($scope.showMenu)
  $scope.showMenu = AuthFactory.loggedStatus(); 
  console.log($scope.showMenu)
  })
})
```

authService

```
angular.module('urbinsight.services')
.factory('AuthFactory', function ($window) {
var isLogged = false;

return {
  check: function() {
    if ($window.sessionStorage.token && $window.sessionStorage.user) {
      isLogged = true;
    } else {
      isLogged = false;
      delete this.user;
    }
  },
  loggedStatus: function() {
    return isLogged;
  },
  changeLoggedStatus: function() {
    isLogged = !(isLogged);
  }
};
})
```

login function + broadcast

```
  login.submit = function () {
  var username = user.username,
    password = user.password;

  if (username !== undefined && password !== undefined) {
    UserAuthFactory.login(username, password).success(function(data) {

      $rootScope.showMenu = true
      // AuthFactory.isLogged = true;
      AuthFactory.changeLoggedStatus();
      AuthFactory.user = data.user.username;
      AuthFactory.userRole = data.user.role;

      $rootScope.$broadcast('loginStateChange');

      $window.sessionStorage.token = data.token;
      $window.sessionStorage.user = data.user.username;
      $window.sessionStorage.userRole = data.user.role;
      $location.path('/');
    }).error(function(status) {
      $window.alert('Oops something went wrong!');
    });
  } else {
    $window.alert('Invalid credentials');
  }
};
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Could post the section of code where you broadcast 'loginStateChange' after you successfully login?

Comment: Done. I added it at the bottom, it is a function in the login Ctrl which is handled on a login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the "$rootScope.showMenu = true" in your login controller. But in your header controller you also have "$scope.showMenu = AuthFactory.loggedStatus();"

So i would remove this line from your header controller

```
$scope.showMenu = AuthFactory.loggedStatus();
```

Since you want your header html to react to $rootscope showMenu variable directly

Comment: Thank you for this. It seems that it was working but not updating correctly when rendered. I removed the line as mentioned because I think the logic of the operation is better.